# Call base() from derived class to execute base class function?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

Sorry for the confusing title.

This should be a fairly simple question

```
public abstract class Base
{
   public virtual void Hello()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello ");
   }
}   

public class Derived : Base
{
   public override void Hello()
   { 
     base();
     Console.WriteLine("World!");
   }
}
```

I have an abstract class with some default implementation.  These virtual methods are used in other methods within the abstract class. The child class needs to add some functionality to the virtual methods, so I want to do something like the above.  I'm not able to call base(), so how do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call it like:

```
 base.Hello();
```

Comment: I didn't even think to try it.  That syntax doesn't work, but base.Hello(); works

Comment: @CSharpDev - Yes of course it should be `base.Hello()` it was a typo=)